# what gem/library to work with Google Calendar API data received via ruby oauth plugin and oauth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

what gem/library to work with Google Calendar API data received via ruby oauth plugin and oauth gem?

Just wondering what Ruby developers using oauth are using to work with the actual calendar data for Google Calendar api.

Comment: I have the same question... Bump on this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The [google-api-ruby-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) seems to do the job.

Coincidentally, I was pursing the same use case, and after stubbing my toes on oauth 1 vs 2 and partial answers for wiring it all together, I created a gem, [google_oauth_calendar](https://github.com/deafgreatdane/google_oauth_calendar), that provides a generator that does the essential configuration to enable a fresh app to authenticate against Google users and then query their calendar information. After configuring your Console API project, it's essentially a 1 liner to install all the related items. The essence can be seen in the [generator code](https://github.com/deafgreatdane/google_oauth_calendar/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/google_oauth_calendar/install/install_generator.rb)